# DocuSign REST API full name tag

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope using DocuSign REST API with two recipients. Each recipient has two sets of tags - sign here tag and a full name tag.

When an envelope gets created, the sign here tags are showing up correctly for both recipients but the the full name tags for the second recipient is showing up for the first recipient.

I am passing the correct document id and recipient id for both tags in the API request.

Adding my code here..

```
    Public Function SetSignerProperties(ByVal signer As Recipient) As DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer
    Dim dssigner As New DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer
    If Not signer Is Nothing Then
        dssigner.Name = signer.name
        dssigner.Email = signer.email
        dssigner.AccessCode = signer.accesscode
        dssigner.AddAccessCodeToEmail = signer.addAccessCodeToEmail
        dssigner.Note = signer.note
        dssigner.RoutingOrder = signer.routingOrder
        dssigner.RecipientId = signer.recipientrecid

        If signer.IsCaptiveRecipient Then
            dssigner.ClientUserId = signer.recipientrecid
            dssigner.EmbeddedRecipientStartURL = signer.embeddedRecipientStartURL
        End If

        'set up the signer tabs..
        AddRecipientTags(signer, dssigner)
    End If
    Return dssigner
End Function

   Public Function AddRecipientTags(ByVal recp As Recipient, ByVal signer As DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer)

    If Not signer Is Nothing Then
        If Not recp.tabs Is Nothing Then
            signer.Tabs = New DocuSign.eSign.Model.Tabs
            For Each currtab In recp.tabs
                Select Case currtab.tabType
                    Case "Sign Here"
                        'it is a signer tab..
                        If signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs Is Nothing Then
                            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = New List(Of DocuSign.eSign.Model.SignHere)
                        End If

                        Dim signheretab As New DocuSign.eSign.Model.SignHere
                        If Not currtab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent Is Nothing Then
                            signheretab.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = currtab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent
                        End If

                        signheretab.AnchorString = currtab.anchorString
                        signheretab.AnchorUnits = currtab.anchorUnits
                        signheretab.AnchorXOffset = currtab.anchorXOffset
                        signheretab.AnchorYOffset = currtab.anchorYOffset
                        signheretab.ConditionalParentLabel = currtab.conditionalParentLabel
                        signheretab.ConditionalParentValue = currtab.conditionalParentValue
                        signheretab.Name = currtab.name
                        signheretab.Optional = currtab.toptional
                        signheretab.PageNumber = currtab.pageNumber
                        signheretab.RecipientId = currtab.recipientId
                        signheretab.ScaleValue = currtab.scaleValue
                        signheretab.TabId = currtab.tabId
                        signheretab.TabLabel = currtab.tabLabel
                        signheretab.TabOrder = currtab.tabOrder
                        signheretab.XPosition = currtab.xPosition
                        signheretab.YPosition = currtab.yPosition
                        signheretab.DocumentId = currtab.documentId
                        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signheretab)
                Case "Full Name"
                        If signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs Is Nothing Then
                            signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs = New List(Of DocuSign.eSign.Model.FullName)
                        End If
                        Dim tab As New DocuSign.eSign.Model.FullName
                        If Not currtab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent Is Nothing Then
                            tab.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = currtab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent
                        End If
                        tab.AnchorString = currtab.anchorString
                        tab.AnchorUnits = currtab.anchorUnits
                        tab.AnchorXOffset = currtab.anchorXOffset
                        tab.AnchorYOffset = currtab.anchorYOffset
                        If Not currtab.bold Is Nothing Then
                            tab.Bold = currtab.bold
                        End If
                        tab.ConditionalParentLabel = currtab.conditionalParentLabel
                        tab.ConditionalParentValue = currtab.conditionalParentValue
                        tab.DocumentId = currtab.documentId
                        tab.Font = currtab.font
                        tab.FontColor = currtab.fontColor
                        tab.FontSize = currtab.fontSize
                        tab.PageNumber = currtab.pageNumber
                        tab.RecipientId = currtab.recipientId
                        tab.Name = currtab.name
                        tab.TabId = currtab.tabId
                        tab.TabLabel = currtab.tabLabel
                        tab.TabOrder = currtab.tabOrder
                        tab.XPosition = currtab.xPosition
                        tab.YPosition = currtab.yPosition
                        If Not currtab.underline Is Nothing Then
                            tab.Underline = currtab.underline
                        End If
                        signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Add(tab)
                     End Select
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Please advise,

Thanks,
Minal

Comment: Please share the code in your qs

Comment: I edited my original question with the code.

Comment: Also can you also capture API request which is sent to DocuSign, you can capture API logs by following steps as mentioned [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging). Add API Request in the qs as well.

Comment: Whats your anchor string for Recipient1 and Recipient2 FullName's tab, hope it is not same.

Comment: The anchor strings are different for each recipient. Please see the API request with the tabs.

Comment: "recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"jsmith@gmail.com","name":"John Smith","recipientId":"39","routingOrder":"1",
"tabs":{"fullNameTabs":[
{"anchorString":"SUBMITTED BY",
"anchorUnits":"pixels",
"anchorXOffset":"20",
"anchorYOffset":"87",
"documentId":"10",
"recipientId":"39",
"tabId":"2",
"tabLabel":"Full Name","tabOrder":"2"}],
"}},

Comment: {"email":"jowner@gmail.com",
"name":"Joe Owner",
"recipientId":"40","routingOrder":"2",
"tabs":{"fullNameTabs":[
{"anchorString":"ACCEPTED BY",
"anchorUnits":"pixels",
"anchorXOffset":"20",
"anchorYOffset":"87",
"documentId":"10","name":"Sign Off By Client","recipientId":"40","tabId":"3","tabLabel":"Sign here","tabOrder":"1"}]

Comment: I posted two recipient tabs in two different posts ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169110/discussion-between-amit-k-bist-and-juiced-tech).

Comment: Please update complete create envelope API logs in your qs post (not as comment), so that we can run it on our account and see why it is not working as you expect it to work.

Comment: Also `"tabLabel": "Signhere"` is present for FullName tab for the second recipient, I think its not correct.

Comment: Sign here tab labels are showing up for the signature tab. I am able to run the same code with the same tags in the Docusign demo environment fine.

Comment: Edit qs and paste the exact API JSON req captured from the DS API logs, you can omit the sensitive data like email etc, I will try to run it my account. Also try hitting same JSON using POSTMAN directly in PROD, and see if you get the error. If JSON is working in Demo then it should work in PROD as well.